# How to test in-app purchase in android without real credit or debit card?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, credit-card

I am using in-app purchase in my android app.
Procedure is all done when i try to purchase it asks me to add a debit or credit card to purchase that item.
I want to know that can I somehow purchase that item with test credit or debit card just to complete the buying procedure.

Secondly in which listener i should actually allow to access the purchased item to user?

```
1- OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener
2- QueryInventoryFinishedListener
3- OnConsumeFinishedListener
```

or

```
4- onActivityResult
```

I am new to in-app purchase. Please suggest the right way.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you really need an active Google Wallet account in order to test your In-App purchase even if it's just a test-order.

Considering the *"access to the purchased item"*. You should use the `OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener` method since this will only be called if the user successfully bought the item. The `QueryInventoryFinishedListener` method should be used if you're trying to restore a purchase.
And always check for the `SKU` of the different IAB-Items:

**Example (OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener):**

```
if(purchaseInfo.getSku().equals("MY_SKU")){
  ...
}
```

**Example (QueryInventoryFinishedListener):**

```
if(inventory.hasPurchase("MY_SKU")){
  ...
}
```